# Boot Receiver Android Studio no inicia

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android Studio con Java, que ejecuta un servicio en segundo plano, sin embargo, me pidieron que el servicio se ejecute automáticamente al iniciar el teléfono sin necesidad de abrir la aplicación, intente implementarlo usando un BroadcastReceiver, sin embargo, al iniciar el teléfono, simplemente no se ejecuta nada, solo se ejecuta al abrir la app como lo hacía antes, a pesar de que configure el archivo del manifiesto como debería, este es el código:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
//resto del código del manifest
<receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
//Resto del codigo del manifest
```

Código de la clase BootReceiver

```
    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String rol="Usuario";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Se esta ejecutando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, DenunciaService.class);
            //Resto de acciones a ejecutar....
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
//Resto de mis metodos...
}
```

Espero que exista una solucion, aún soy un estudiante, por lo que no soy 100% experto en el tema.

Comment: Importante revisar el LogCat y obtendrás información que puedes agregar a tu pregunta.